# execute additional code if specific type of exception occur

Tags: python

I want to execute an additional code in the except, only if IndexError occurs:

```
try:
   execute code if no error
except IndexError:
   execute code 1
   execute code 2
except: #any other except type
   execute code 1
```

I don't want to type the same code (code 1) 2 times inside both exceptions

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a function for execute code 1?

```
def execute_code_1():
    #wirte code here
```